# Haskell, range downto without step

Tags: haskell, range

Why in Haskell is not working range downto without step

```
[7..1] => []
```

but working only this

```
[7,6..1] => [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 3.10. Arithmetic sequences
>
> [...]
>   Arithmetic sequences satisfy these identities:
>
> - [...]
> - [ e1..e3 ]  =   enumFromTo e1 e3
> - [...]
>
> 6.3.4 The Enum Class
>
> For the types Int and Integer, the enumeration functions have the following meaning:
>
> - [...]
> - The sequence enumFromTo e1 e3 is the list [e1,e1 + 1,e1 + 2,…e3]. The list is empty if e1  >  e3.
> - [...]

From [Haskell 2010 Language Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).

Answer (score 13):

Haskell has no way to know that you want to step -1 until you give it a hint.

There might be situations where you want a range `[x..y]` where `y < x` and where you expect the range to be empty. This would create subtle bugs if Haskell would simply step downwards in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Without an indication of the step, haskell assumes it to be +1 and returns an empty list if it's not applicable to the given parameters.

*Any* increment apart from +1 has to be explicitly suggested; not only positive integrers > 1.