# Why is [1..n] not handled the same way as [n..1] in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I was trying to solve a problem that required the maximum value of a list after being mapped over by a function. The list is a range from a to b where a>b or b>a. Because Haskell can also define decreasing lists i thought that i didn't need to check if a>b and there was no need to flip the bounds to b..a. The function looks somewhat like this:

```
f a b = maximum . map aFunction $ [a..b]
```

But if the list is decreasing i.e. a>b then Haskell gives me an exception:

```
Prelude.maximum: empty list
```

So for some reason a decreasing list hands over an empty list to the maximum function. Why is that?

I know that `maximum` is defined in terms of a `foldl1 max` and that `foldl1` needs a non empty list but i don't know why a list like `[10..1]` is empty when handed to a `foldl1`.

Comment: `[10..1]` is empty whatever you do with it (even if you don't hand it to `foldl1`). This is how the range is defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell, range downto without step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972599/haskell-range-downto-without-step).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806455/haskell-list-range-question as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`[a..b]` desugars to `enumFromTo a b`. For standard numeric types (modulo a couple of quirks for floating), this keeps adding one until you are `>= b`. So where `b < a` this is empty.

You can change the increment by using the following syntax `[a,a'..b]` which then takes steps in increments of `a'-a`. So `[10,9..1]` will be what you want.

Comment: Thanks that really did it. I totally forgot about the stepping.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of the way the sequence is defined in [Haskell Report Arithmetic Sequences](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10)
:

> [ e1..e3 ]  =  enumFromTo e1 e3

and [Haskell Report The Enum Class](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4)

> The sequence enumFromTo e1 e3 is the list [e1,e1 + 1,e1 + 2, ... e3]. **The list is empty if e1  >  e3.**

(emphasis added).

Answer (score 3):

They are handled exactly the same way.  You start from the first bound and count up.